# How to set a datetime field = now() during insert?

Tags: 7, database

I'm using db_insert() to insert a record into a table. That table as a "creationDatetime" field which should be set to now() on insert. I tried setting it to REQUEST_TIME, but that value is a unixtime value and not an sql datetime format so I get an error.

I suppose I could write a php function that will automatically format REQUEST_TIME as an sql datetime value and call that function every time I try to insert, but does anyone else have a better solution?

Comment: why don't you write now() itself in query ?

Comment: Because you don't write a query when using db_insert(), the API constructs the query itself, and putting "now()" as the field value throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a better solution to be honest. Classes like the `SelectQuery` provide an `addExpression()` function so that arbitrary expressions can be added (like `NOW()` etc), but unfortunately the [`InsertQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/class/InsertQuery/7) class provides no such method.

Looks like you're stuck writing the helper function, or building up the SQL string yourself and running it through `db_query()` (I can't say I'd advise the second method though, and I'm sure I've seen it specifically recommended against in the docs somewhere).

Answer (score 7):

Using a slightly different syntax (drupal_write_record):

```
$new_record = array(
    'field' => $form_state['values']['field'],
    'timestamp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()), //<- this
);          
drupal_write_record('table_name', $new_record);
```

Comment: This ony saves the date not the time. hOW TO SAVE ALSO THE TIME? :)

Comment: this not work time diff in both server

Answer (score 2):

[db_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7) returns an InsertQuery object. It allows you to set any field value you want to set. Just use the [php time() function](http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.time.php) to pass in the current unix time stamp.

Comment: As I explained in my post, I don't want the unix time, I want an sql date format.

Answer (score 0):

Let to chime in but here is a solution.  Just use db_query.  Here is my code I used that worked.  And yes, this is a Drupal 7 solution.  Thanks.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO {company_cmi_session_time} uid,scoid,gid,datetime,initialize,terminate) VALUES (:uid,:scoid,:gid,NOW(),1,1)";
$result = db_query($query, array(':uid' => $uid, ':scoid' => $nid, ':gid' => $groupid));
```